# odoo8 pass userID in scheduler in argument.

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I am trying to execute the scheduler but I need to pass the user id in the parameter when execute the scheduler.

```
<record forcecreate="True" id="ir_cron_daily_study" model="ir.cron">
           <field name="name">Fetch Data</field>
           <field eval="True" name="active" />
           <field name="user_id" ref="base.user_root"/>
           <field name="interval_number">1</field>
           <field name="interval_type">minutes</field>
           <field name="numbercall">-1</field>
           <field name="doall" eval="False"/>
           <field name="model" eval="'fetch.data'"/>
           <field name="function" eval="'fetch_data'"/>
           <field name="args" eval="()" />
       </record>
```

I tried to pass the args like

```
<field name="args" eval="({'check': True})" />
```

I am getting this value but not able to pass the user id.
Please help me to pass the user Id during the execution of ir_cron job.

Suggestions are most welcome.

Comment: What about setting the user_id in the xml directly? `<field name="user_id" >1</field>`

Comment: Thanks for response, but I need the ID of the user that I need to use in my method.

Answer (score 1):

The `ir.cron` jobs by default run with the superuser's id. Check `openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_cron.py` _defaults attribute.

If you want to pass the user id you have to :

`<field name="args" eval="(uid, )" />`

Check the definition of `ir_cron` model, for further explanation.

<strike>From what I can see though, the method of the cron job is always run with the superuser's id.</strike>

**Edit**: Correction to the above,  @CZoellner is right on mentioning that your can set the user who will run the cron job. Still, this is a static variable and you cannot determine who will run the job in runtime from what I can understand. While you can pass different parameters to the cron job.

Thank you for the correction  @CZoellner

Comment: It gives the error,  ValidateError

Field(s) `args` failed against a constraint: Invalid arguments

Comment: The job is called with the configured `user_id` --> [Odoo Code](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/9.0/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_cron.py#L162) as i wrote in the first comment on the question.

Comment: @CZoellner You are correct, I have edited the answer.

Comment: I only see use cases for UIDs in args, if you have to use multiple users for a cron, because it is static, too.

Comment: If you want to use multiple users for a cron, you could get them all using a search and browse and then run the method for each one of them. This is a basically a workaround.